# Can't connect to MySQL from PHP but can from CLI

Tags: php, mysql, linux

Since today morning I cannot connect to my MySQL from any of the two web servers via PHP, but I can connect via command line

I've checked, there is no bind-address in the /etc/my.conf, the user with which I'm connecting has all privileges and is allow to connect as

```
'<user>'@'%'
'<user>'@'localhost'
'<user>'@'127.0.0.1'
'<user>'@'<web-server-1-ip-internal>'
'<user>'@'<web-server-1-ip-external>'
'<user>'@'<web-server-2-ip-internal>'
'<user>'@'<web-server-2-ip-external>'
```

(above external is fully resolved ip and internal is 10.xxx.xxx.xxx)

I've tried to start/restart and reinstall the mysql server, there's nothing in the error logs (/var/log/mysqld.log is actually a few days old which is weird).

I'm using a simply php script to connect

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('<db-server-ip>', '<user>', '<password>');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);

?>
```

This gives me the

```
Could not connect: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial 
communication   packet', system error: 110
```

I did check firewall rules and /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny as well as (although this can't be the issue as CLI connection works just fine)

Any ideas short of rebuilding the server (which may not help anyways)

Comment: Maybe a dump suggestion, but can you ping your mysql server from any of your 2 webservers? Has there been a change of IP adresses? Maybe FLUSH HOSTS on MySQL?

Comment: but I can connect via command line ... just to be sure tried `mysqladmin flush-hosts`

Comment: When you say you can connect "via the command line" do you mean you're able to connect using the mysql CLI utility from web-server-1 and web-server-2?